# Find camera orientation && translation from 2d image

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

The Goal ::

I intend to have an uploaded image as a static background, and render 3d objects on a designated plane in that image.

I need to get the orientation of the camera, in relation to the plane. So then I can properly render the 3D models on said plane.

The user will specify the length & width of the plane. As well as outline the plane, resulting in the plane's 4 corners ( A,B,C,D on the 2D image ).

[image: diagram]

---

What I've tried ::

I've looked at using webassembly ported OpenCV, particularly `solvePnP`, but while testing I was getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$' of undefined at RegisteredPointer.nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType`

Code I was using below:

```
// 3D world coords
var vv = cv.matFromArray( 4,3,cv.CV_32SC1,[
    0,0,0,
    0,4,0,
    8,4,0,
    8,0,0,
])

// 2D img coords
var imageP = cv.matFromArray( 4,2,cv.CV_8S,[
    292,272,
    72,379,
    487,530,
    701,470,
])

// camera internal params
var cm = new cv.Mat(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1,new cv.Scalar())

var rvec
var tvec
cv.solvePnP( vv, imageP, cm, new cv.Mat(), rvec, tvec, false, cv.SOLVEPNP_P3P )
```

---

With the known variables, is it possible to glean any information about the camera's orientation / position / FOV?

Comment: it would probably be easier for you to start having a plane of a known size with some unique identifier on it that is rotation invariant and can be found in any image. From there you would have the angle of rotation, and you'd probably need to outline the plane from there in order to find the skew. After you have the angle of rotation and the skew, you could map an affine rectangle to the known plane (either with user entered dimensions or preferably pre defined ones) and from there you could use the affine rectangle to determine changes you need to make for the mapped object to be displayed.

Comment: have a look at solvePnP

Answer (score 1):

The answer is abit more complex.

First, you have to calibrate camera to get cameraMatrix. You should also remove distortion along the way,

```
var cm = new cv.Mat(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1,new cv.Scalar())
```

In ur code, you just declare it and did not put any content to it. and the math requires it as shown below
[image] 
[image]
then You need to know the physical size of the object in order to do that.

The easiest way for you to start is you use chessboard calibration pattern sample which you can pre-enter its size.

You can follow this sample to find how to find the camera orientation and relative position to pre-determined objects.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

The source code to achieve what you want is here 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp

Start from line 1400.

The sample result with AR can be found in this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hek-DmiGEw
[image]

[image]